# SQL truncate column names

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am working on MS ACCESS 2003 and I would like to truncate colomn name by using left expression. The problem left expression is applied only on data and not on column name. I tried also to use alias but alias cannot be duplicated.
Let me show you my dataset and the result that I want to get.

My dataset:

```
Reference | 1S44 combined % | 1S44 combined of | 1S44 forward % | 1S44 forward of
B15       | 44.77           | 1224             | 44.73          | 550
```

In result, I would like to truncate column names `1S44 combined %`, `1S44 combined of`, `1S44 forward %` and `1S44 forward of` into one column `Echt` as below:

```
Echt | Ref | 1S44 combined % | 1S44 combined of | 1S44 forward % | 1S44 forward of
1S44 | B15 | 44.77           | 1224             | 44.73          | 550
```

Hope someone could help me.

Comment: Is this a report? Is this the resultset of a query?

Comment: Hi nimcomp, it is a resultset of a query that I want to get. I tried select RawData.[1S44 combined %] as 1S44, RawData.[14S combined of] from RawData. But I cannot duplicate alias.

Comment: Post your SQL. I don't understand your requirements.

Comment: I tried to populate Echt row with the first 4 characters of the name of column. the thing it takes the 4 first characters of the values inside the row and not the row name.UPDATE RawData2 INNER JOIN RawData ON RawData2.[10S44 combined %] = RawData.[1S44 combined %] SET RawData2.Echt = Left(RawData.[1S44 combined %],5);

Comment: I guess if all you need is more control over column headings then I'd suggest using a report or a form based on the query, then you could name the headings anything you want. What are you planning to do with the query?

Comment: Complete stab in the dark here, you want to update Echt to '1S44 ', not the values of the fields?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I actually wanted to truncate column name to group by elements. Just taking the first 4 characters of column name. I didn't find any SQAL query which can do that.